What site to post a question about uBlock?
I created a question µBlock: How to Add a CSS-class in a Filter? on Web Applications Stack Exchange, but it was flagged as off-topic. On which site should I ask this question?

Did the advice given to you in the comments there not help?

I'm refering to the reference to SuperUser as the comment may have slipped your attention.

@W.O. Well, to me SuperUser doesn't fit, but I guess I'll post it there then. Thanks.

The reason this fits on SuperUser is that it's about using the software that's on your computer (in this case, the web browser). Web Applications SE is about software where the website that you are connected to is the software.

Question seems fine in its current form for Super User
